# Google Docs's drag & drop file upload. How is it possible?

Tags: html, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, google-docs

Google docs now supports drag & drop upload.

How did they do?
How did they implement progressbar for uploading file? Did they use HTML5 websocket?
If I use XMLHttpRequest for the uplaod, is there a way to show a progressbar to user?

By the way, a folder still can not be upload in Google docs yet. Is it impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a [HTML5](http://html5doctor.com/native-drag-and-drop/) feature.

Comment: Then, even though we use HTML5, we can't upload a folder by d&d?